# Continue a list in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list in excel, like this:

```
Name            Count
Product A       5
Product B       10
Product C       12
```

Now the whole point is that I can sort the list alphabetically from time to time so I can insert the other counts easier.
Now my question is, can I continue the list on the right of the excel sheet instead of going lower and still sort it as a whole? Heres what I mean:

```
Name            Count                Name            Count
Product A       5                    Product D       12
Product B       7                    
Product C       9
```

What I mean, is there some way I can sort this kind of list alphabetically or export it as a whole list?

Comment: IMHO, as far as tables and data are concerned, I think one record should be in one row. If there are multiple records per row (as in your case), it will not be possible to mix both rows and perform a sort operation. I suggest that you make a single table with `Name` and `Count` headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware that Excel will allow you to present a table in a multi-column layout as you've described. However, perhaps an acceptable solution for your application is to store the table in Excel as you normally would (all data in a single table, one column for all names, another for all counts). Next, copy this table and Paste to Word, the configure your Word page with columns as needed.  A couple of things to note:

- Paste Link (use Paste Special) to ensure your Excel changes are reflected in Excel as you add/modify data
- Copy/Paste just the data, without headers, and handle headers in your Word document (so they'll repeat at top of each column)

If you have problems with the top alignment of your two columns, add a Table in Word (just one column x one row), and Paste Link to this cell.

Another option, still using Word but without using multiple columns, is to create two Text Boxes in Word (one for each column). Position them side by side, just like a two column layout. Paste Link your data in the left side box, and then Link the left box to the right, so content flows. For help with Linked Text Boxes, see http://wordribbon.tips.net/T011668_Linking_Text_Boxes.html